# Three.js Camera always undefined when setting up ray tracing

Tags: angular, three.js

I have created a three.js element to show a number of points on the screen and I have been tasked with clicking on two and calculating the distance between them. I am doing this in a Angular (8) app and have all the points visible and mouse events (pointerup/down) set up correctly. My idea is to ray trace from the mouse point when clicked and highlight a vertex (I do only have points no lines or faces). So I have attempted to set up Three.js RayTRacing on my scene but every time I call setFromCamera the camera is undefined even though I srill have the points visible on the screen at all times.

```
public onMouseDown(event){    

    var mx = event.clientX;
    var my = event.clientY;
    
    this.caster.setFromCamera({x: mx, y: my}, this.camera);
    const intersections = this.caster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);

    console.log("Mouse is down! " + mx + " " + my);
  }
```

If I remove the two lines involving the caster I get my x & y outputs. This next snippet is called through ngAFterInit:

```
public configRaycaster(){
    this.caster = new THREE.Raycaster();    
  }
```

As far as I am concerned all is set up and I should be working out which object was clicked but, obviously, it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I need arrow functions to set up the eventListener otherwise this is local to the function.

```
this.container.nativeElement.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => this.onMouseDown(event), false);
```

not

```
this.container.nativeElement.addEventListener('pointerup', this.onMouseDown, false);
```